# trying to reverse what a conditional has executed

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have made an "if" conditional.
if var a > 6, a code will be executed.
however. there is a chance that later on while the user interacts with the page, var a will no longer be greater than 6. therefore i want to take back the action the conditional has executed (for my spesific need: a delete of a div).

my code:

```
if(divNum > 5) {
var lastDiv = $("div:nth-last-child(3)");
lastDiv.remove();}
```

how do i reverse the action and get this div back?

Comment: Once it has been removed (and if you didn't keep a reference to what you removed), the only way to get it back is to recreate the content and insert it.  You'd have to know what the content was and exactly where it was inserted.

Comment: if that is so.. i will change the remove into some kind of hiding effect. the idea is this. this div i'm about to hide is a widget. i want it to hide because there are too many widgets on the screen. but when i exit another widget using a button, there aren't too many widgets anymore so i want it back.

any tips on how its done?

Comment: Then, you can do `lastDiv.hide()` and `lastDiv.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to **[.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)** the element for later use.

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

```
var lastDiv = $("div:nth-last-child(3)");

function checkDivNum(divNum) {
    if (divNum > 5) {
        lastDiv.detach();
    } else {
        lastDiv.appendTo('body');
    }
}

checkDivNum(7);

// Wait 3 seconds... then show again...
setTimeout(function () {
    checkDivNum(4);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: so first, this works great. BUT, it shows the div after the specified amount of seconds without taking into account if there's room for the div.

I mean. i want only 5 divs to be shown at a time (or 6). here it just shows it after 3 seconds even if there are more than the amount i want